# In PHP, how can I find elements in one array that are not in another?

Tags: php

Is there a php function, similar to array_merge, that does the exact opposite? In other words, I have two arrays. I would like to remove any value that exists in the second array from the first array. I could do this by iterating with loops, but if there is a handy function available to do the same thing, that would be the preferred option.

Example:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array2 = [2, 4, 5]

$result = array_unmerge(array1, array2);
```

$result should come out to [1, 3]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to compute the difference between two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$array2 = array(2, 4, 5);

$array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($array3);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/gXKPrfBV)

Comment: +1 for description, link to docs, code, output, and demo. Complete, well-organized answer.

Comment: Beautiful. That is exactly what I was looking for, and I'm almost ashamed I couldn't find it by searching. Thank you

Comment: @JoshuaZollinger: No worries :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
 $array2 = array(2, 4, 5);
 $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.